# Displaying max() value of table that has nested table column

Tags: database, oracle, abstract-data-type

lets say I have a nested table called test:

```
create table test(
     id int,
     name varchar2(20),
     production row_type_value,
     constraint pk_country primary_key(id)
) nested table production store as country_production;
```

the types are:

```
    create or replace type type_value as OBJECT(
        year int,
        value int
    );
    /
    create or replace type row_type_value as table of type_value;
```

there is a way to just in one query get the max(value) of the production column of all countries given a year for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may make use of `TABLE` function.

```
SELECT t.id,
       MAX(p.value)
FROM test t
CROSS JOIN TABLE ( production ) p
GROUP BY t.id;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ffd2baf0907e996bbaaf69fd46aeca34)